# Angular 2/4 - Manage the response without a return value?

Tags: angular, angular-http

please, tell me.

There are queries in which there is no return value, but there is a status code. I would like to issue messages based on this code. The function works, but does not go into the showNotification method.

```
......

let params = new URLSearchParams();
      params.set('token', token);
      this.http.get(CaSettings.API_HOME_LOGOUT, new RequestOptions({params: params, headers: this.getHeaders()}))
.map(this.showNotification)
.subscribe();
}

......

  showNotification(res: Response) {
    if (res.status == 200) {
      this.notification.success("success", "success")
    }
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Change `map(this.showNotification)` to `map(res => this.showNotification(res))` and add a console.log to your showNotification method. If the console log doesn't display, it means the request fails.

Comment: It works. Issue has been resolved, thank you!

Comment: Then it means that showNotification **was** being called, but that it threw an error. You should have found that error in the console.

Comment: Yes I understand. I'm in debug mode. I have a global error handling.